# JavaScript Functions & Equations

Tags: javascript, forms, math

I'm trying to complete a simple multiplication problem of an input and a number already there (5.49) using JavaScript and the Compute function. I have it inside of a table and am using internal css for the structure of the page. 
My problem is the when I press the compute button on the page, the answer to the equation (input)*5.49 doesn't come up, but instead nothing does. I'm struggling to find mistake.
Additional Notes: I've already checked to see if the compute button was working by replacing the formula with a pop-up box and it was working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <style type="text" /css>
    .inbox { width=30px; text-align: right; border: 2px solid black; } .align { text-align: right }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function compute() {
      var a = form1.inputA.value;
      a = parseFloat(a);
      var b = form1.inputB.value;
      b = parseFloat(b);
      var c = form1.inputC.value;
      c = parseFloat(c);
      var e = a * 5.49;
      form1.sumA.value = e.toFixed(2);
    }

    function pageInit() {
      form1.inputA.focus();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="pageInit();">
  <form id="form1">
    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Sample Order Form</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>item</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Totals</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input tabindex="1" class="inbox" type="text" id="inputA" />
        </th>
        <th>Apples</th>
        <td>$5.49</td>
        <th>
          <input class="inbox" type="text" id="sumA" readonly="readonly" />
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input tabindex="4" type="button" value="Compute" onclick="compute();" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this is JavaScript, why the `java` tag? Tags changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields `inputB` and `inputC` just don't exist. Then it produce an error.

```
function compute() {
   var a = form1.inputA.value;
   a = parseFloat(a);
   var e = a * 5.49;
   form1.sumA.value = e.toFixed(2);
}
```

You can use web developer tools to analyze your code.
Modern web browser have tools like that.
Take a look at google chrome developer tools : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools for example. You can find equivalent tools for firefox and Internet Explorer.